# How should I store my sha512 salted & hashed passwords in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, security

All,

I am using the following PHP function to salt & hash user passwords for a web app:

```
function stringHashing($password,$salt){
 $hashedString=$password.$salt;
 for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++){
  $hashedString=hash('sha512',$password.$hashedString.$salt);
  }
 return $hashedString;
}
```

What is the best way to store the resulting string in MySQL?  I suppose it is a fixed CHAR field?  How should I go about calculating the right length?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: This may help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319588/storing-hashed-passwords-in-mysql.

Comment: why aren't you using a third parameter for the number of times to rehash the string?

Comment: Not a duplicate - my question is about sha512, not SHA-1.

Comment: @JDelage Practically, how does SHA512 differ from SHA-1? Therein lies the answer (and the "duplicate", as it applies ;-)

Comment: @pst - The string output of the 2 algos is of different length.  The answer to the SHA-1 question doesn't explain how to calculate the string length based on the algo.  Therefore, there's no way to answer my question with the SHA-1 question unless you have additional knowledge.

Comment: @JDelage So what is the output size of SHA512? That is the answer. [Wikipedia SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) (and realizing that it takes two hex characters to encode 8 bits) contains all the information needed. It would be beneficial to apply some *critical thinking* and *judicial searching* before posting an "exciting" question such as this. I will pull up the other relevant documentation (such as that of the PHP documentation), if you wish.

Comment: **Don't use SHA512 for passwords!**

Comment: @ScottArciszewski - this is an old question but still: why not, and if not SHA512 then what else?

Comment: [How to safely store your users' passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016). Don't use a fast hash like SHA512, use a *password hash* (compound noun) instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, SHA512 will always return a 512 bit hash, the two-argument `hash()` method returns this as hex digits, so that's 512 bits / 8 bits per byte * 2 hex digits per byte = 128 hex digits

A `CHAR(128)` should be what you need

Answer (score 1):

I have always used a varchar field with a more-than-needed length. What if, down the road, you want to change your algorithm? You have to alter the table, which is annoying.

SHA512 will produce a 128 char string, so give the field at least that.

Also, I must point out that you are doing a lot of wasted processing. You are not adding too much security by iterating through the same salt and hash over and over and over again. Ultimately, you will still need a salt and password, everything else about the algorithm remains constant.

Comment: In this case the size is well-known, just as say for a GUID. It's not someones name so there is no "Mr. WhatchaCallitIHadParentsWhoWantedToPlayAPracticalJoke". If the requirement changes later, then change the schema... later.

Comment: "Also, I must point out that you are doing a lot of wasted processing. You are not adding too much security by iterating through the same salt and hash over and over and over again."  I did that based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559437/many-hash-iterations-append-salt-every-time/3559497#3559497

Comment: (Although, I wonder if the same can be said about using SHA-2/SHA-512 and not SHA-1... but I'm no cypto expert.)

Comment: @JDelage they're using a variable number of runs, while with yours, it stays constant. Think of hashing sorta like taking a derivative: All constant data no longer matters because you're representing a rate of change. In terms of data security, this is equally true because even though you're iterating it 50 times, that does not change between other items to be hashed.

Comment: Fascinating - I had completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

If someone knows your salt, they probably have your source code which guides them to repeat it 50 times. In that light, given the trivial security benefit to recursive re-hashing with a fixed-count, I thought I'd suggest using [SHA2()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) from MySQL 5.5.5+ as a neater alternative:

```
mysql_query("SELECT SHA2(CONCAT('$password','$salt'), 512) AS `hash`;");
```

Which will be your `VARCHAR(128)` ready to `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.