# How to get php session value into mysql trigger

Tags: php, mysql, session, triggers

How can I get a field value from php session (userid) to use it in mysql triggers

My Trigger :

```
 BEGIN
 IF NEW.nombre <> OLD.nombre THEN
        INSERT INTO socios_history (socio_id,tabla,campo, old_value, new_value,lstuser,updated) VALUES (old.socio_id,'usuarios','nombre',old.nombre,new.nombre,XXXXX,now());
    END IF;
 IF NEW.email <> OLD.email THEN
        INSERT INTO socios_history (socio_id,tabla,campo, old_value, new_value,lstuser,updated) VALUES (old.socio_id,'usuarios','email',old.email,new.email,XXXXX,now());
    END IF;
END
```

XXXXXX will be the userid from `$_SESSION["userid"];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7750208/829970

Comment: It would be easier if you put userid somewhere in your database, probably in your row NEW.userid

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm running the trigger, from a web app, and the user is logged in and credentials save in php session

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you mean. It would be great if you could clean up your question a bit. From what im getting so far is that you want to retrieve a stored value from your session.

During the login you should have stored the users username into the session variable basically:

```
....mysql query checking for login
if login success
$_SESSION['userid'] = $username;
```

Then to retrieve it during your triggers make a variable for it

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

IF NEW.nombre <> OLD.nombre THEN INSERT INTO socios_history (socio_id,tabla,campo, old_value, new_value,lstuser,updated) VALUES (old.socio_id,'usuarios','nombre','old.nombre','new.nombre','$userid',now());
```

Comment: Hi, thank you Yuria, thats what I'm trying to do, I already insert this line "$userid = $_SESSION['userid']; into the Trigger but I'm receiving a Syntax Error.

Comment: You also want to make sure in the php file that you're running that there is an active session. To solve this problem usually you would have a functions.php and in it would be something like this:if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
}

Comment: Hi:  I already resolve this issue, I add a new field on the users table: "updated_by" and then in the PHP script, where I update the table, I get userID from PHP Session, save on this new field and  the trigger is this way : IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
        INSERT INTO users_history (user_id,tabla,field,old_value, new_value,lstuser,updated) VALUES (old.user,'users','name',old.name,new.name,new.updated_by,now());
    END IF;  And it works for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably set a variable in MySQL when you establish the connection.  (I can verify that the SQL works; haven't tested doing it with PHP.)

```
$set_id = $pdo->prepare('SET @user_id = ?');
$set_id->execute([$_SESSION['userid']]);
```

And have your trigger use `@user_id`.

Note, this may act wacky with persistent connections.