# Is it possible to automatically update table in SQL, when a table is updated?

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables:

**Table Results:**

- id
- homeScore
- awayScore

**Table Ladder:**

- id
- points

**Table Predictions**

- id
- homeScore
- awayScore

I want to add points to **all ids in Table Ladder**, triggered by insertions, modifications or removals in **Table Results**, depending on the **value** of homeScore,awayScore from **table Predictions**.

And I have rules like:

- If user result and real result are identical, **+5 points**
- If user predicted correct winner, **+2 points**
- If user predicted correct goal difference **+3 points**
- If user predicted correct goals scored, **+1 point** (can happen for both teams)

Is this possible with only SQL? If not, how do I approach this with **PHP**?

Comment: You are probably looking for `triggers`. That's as much information as I can give you with the current content of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL Triggers - How to pass variables to trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750208/php-mysql-triggers-how-to-pass-variables-to-trigger)

Comment: I've looked into triggers, it is a bit confusing to me, I've updated my question. Am I able to apply my rules(different points for different outcomes) within triggers? @FirstOne

Comment: @Troix, Yeah, you can have `if`s inside your trigger. That way, it's a matter of defining the conditions and what to do when each one occur. First you should learn the basic of triggers, ex: insert something -> do something else. Then you might want to learn triggers that have different behaviour depending on the value. Since this will introduce the `IF`, it will be easier to create different outcome based on those criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you define triggers. Compare new result with old result upon insert/update/delete and your problem will be solved. Read some tutorials about triggers for the RDBMS you are using and you will be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit & answer, I've looked into triggers, however, I am not sure if I can apply different amount of points depending on values from those columns?